# How do I navigate to a new URL if the page doesn't stop loading?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to navigate through a list of URLs using Selenium and Python. However, some pages don't stop loading and want to navigate to other URLs if that happens. So, I used the `TimeoutException`. However, after getting that exception, the browser doesn't navigate to next URL in the list and keeps trying to load that page.

The code I used is something along the following lines:

```
list_of_urls = [...]    # List of the URLs I wish to navigate to
for i in range(0, len(list_of_urls)):
    try:
        browser.get(list_of_urls[i])
    except TimeoutException:
        print 'Timeout'
        continue
```

How do I make the browser navigate to the next URL in the list in case the page doesn't stop loading?

Comment: Do you see `Timeout` in the output? Have you tried `browser.close()`, `browser.quit()` to restart the browser?

Comment: I see `Timeout` in the output. I don't want to restart browser for every item in the list coz my list is humongous and it will end up consuming a lot of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JFSebastian's suggestion helped. However, I'm not closing the browser though. I am just creating a new tab. What I'm doing is as follows:

```
list_of_urls = [...]    # List of the URLs I wish to navigate to
for i in range(0, len(list_of_urls)):
    try:
        browser.get(list_of_urls[i])
    except TimeoutException:
        print 'Timeout'
        browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')     ## Open new tab
        browser.switch_to_window(main_window)
        browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + Keys.TAB)       ## Focus to previous tab
        browser.switch_to_window(main_window)
        browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')     ## Close current tab
        browser.switch_to_window(main_window)
        browser.get(url)
```

I found this method on lrhache's github [here](https://gist.github.com/lrhache/7686903)

Answer (score 0):

So here is an easy fix I can think of:

```
list_of_urls = [...]    # List of the URLs I wish to navigate to
while i < len(list_of_urls):
    try:
        browser.get(list_of_urls[i])
    except TimeoutException, e:
        print 'Timeout'
    finally:
        i += 1
```

Comment: And what does this fix, exactly?